# How to grant permission to a node for an user programatically?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I am using [ACL](https://www.drupal.org/project/acl) module to set user wise permission . Its working fine and I am able to set permission user wise from admin access.

What I need:

I have the `nid` and `uid` and I wants to set node view access permission to that user programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to program it yourself, you can have something like this, probably implementing [hook_init()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7.x):

```
function my_module_init() {
  global $user;

  $nid = 85; // We'll check node 85.

  // Users with access:
  $uids = array(
    3,
    9,
    11,
  );

  $node_path = 'node/' . $nid;

  // Check if the user is in the node detail.
  if (current_path() == $node_path) {
    // Check if the user is not in the list of allowed users.
    if (!in_array($user->uid, $uids)) {
      drupal_access_denied();
    }
  }
}
```